Segment sentences in Vim
I would like to be able to navigate from sentence to sentence with a keyboard shortcut in Vim.
I know there are commands like (,),{,} for jumping to between sentences or paragraphs, presumably matched using regular expressions. Regular expressions don't work perfectly when working with organic natural language text.
I am familiar with NLP algorithms and libraries that can segment text into sentences, for example Spacy or NLTK.
I am just curious about how to use something like that within Vim.
For example, if I just defined a new Vim motion via a Vim function, I believe a common pattern would be to read in the content of the buffer into a variable, and the current cursor position, and then I can pass that to a program that returns the position of the start of the next sentence:
function! NextNLPSentence()
    " Save cursor position
    let l:saved_pos = getpos('.')
    
    " Get buffer content
    let l:content = join(getline(1, '$'), "\n")
    
    " Get current cursor position as character offset
    let l:cur_line = line('.')
    let l:cur_col = col('.')
    let l:offset = line2byte(l:cur_line) + l:cur_col - 2
    
    " Call external NLP tool via temporary file
    let l:tmp = tempname()
    call writefile([l:content], l:tmp)
    
    " Python script that takes a file path and cursor offset and returns the character offset of the next sentence end
    let l:next_end = system('python3 find_next_sentence.py ' . shellescape(l:tmp) . ' ' . l:offset)
    call delete(l:tmp)
    
    " If we got a valid offset
    if l:next_end =~ '^\d\+$'
        " Convert character offset back to line/column
        let l:new_pos = byte2line(l:next_end + 1)
        let l:new_col = l:next_end - line2byte(l:new_pos) + 2
        
        " Move cursor
        call cursor(l:new_pos, l:new_col)
    else
        " Revert on error
        call setpos('.', l:saved_pos)
        echoerr "Failed to find next sentence"
    endif
endfunction

" Map to ) in normal mode
nnoremap <silent> ) :call NextNLPSentence()<CR>

" Make it work with operators too (d), c), etc)
onoremap <silent> ) :call NextNLPSentence()<CR>

This is definitely one approach, but I'm curious about others.
For example, should I analyze the file and insert "marks" - like hidden tokens marking the sentences? Or use "text objects"?

You can only insert 26 arbitrary marks so that method won't scale. Not sure why you bring up text objects as they are just special motions and you are already doing motions. If your current method does what you want, then there is no point asking for an alternative. "Trying to write" an alternative, maybe, but that's not what you are doing.

I'm interested to understand better about the weakness of the Vim sentence. The only one I'm aware of is sentence that contains abbreviations (e.g.: Tom Cruise a.k.a. Ethan Hunt is not told. is subdivided in two sentences where it should be only one). Could you illustrate the weakness with other examples?

If you absolutely wanted to store positions, you could roll your own buffer-local cache or use textprops.

The only weakness about Vim sentence that I'm aware of is about sentences that contains abbreviations.
e.g.:
Tom Cruise a.k.a. Ethan Hunt is not told.

is considered by vanilla Vim as two sentences where it should be only one.
To circumvent that weakness you could be interested by the following vim-textobj-sentence plugin.

(My vote is half for the answer and half for the example. Thanks for the chuckle!)
